# Does Eyshot have any function to auto join the lines?

Tags: eyeshot

Given 3 lines as shown in the image, I would like to automatically make them connect to each other to a single point, given some threshold for movement. Assuming that the other endpoint cannot be moved.  I am trying to find some functions but I cannot find one.

[image]

Comment: That's a simple loop to merge points that are close to each other based on a criteria. For lines you take each lines `StartPoint` and `EndPoint` and check if any other line `StartPoint` or `EndPoint` are close enough and update those line point to match yours.

Comment: @Franck, thanks. For some reason, I thought, it must be done via some complex math function.